# I am using Blob for hide URL of the video. But unable to find exact Video Codec information

Tags: video, html5-video, blob, codec

I am using Blob for hide URL of the video. But unable to find exact Video Codec information

var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.4d002a, mp4a.40.2"';

here is the code. which i am trying to use.

https://github.com/nickdesaulniers/netfix/blob/gh-pages/demo/bufferAll.html

How can i find my video codec.

Thanks

Comment: Not enough useful information... **(1)** Is your input video (blob) actually holding MP4 data? **(2)** If yes to MP4, then is it a fragmented MP4, and do you have some **initialization** MP4 to send first to MSE? .... Alternatively just use a media player on your computer that tells you the codec info (a player like VLC or a tool like FFmpeg).

Comment: First of all thanks for your response. 

I used this link to get details of my video
https://nickdesaulniers.github.io/mp4info/

MediaSource supported by your browser.
is fragmented: false
track #0 codec string: avc1.42c016
track #1 codec string: mp4a.40.2
MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42c016, mp4a.40.2"'); // => true

Can i do fragmented in php on run time? because i have more 5000 Videos on my website. 

Thanks

Comment: Boss. i found the codec. but my video is not fregmented. How can i do this using PHP at run time?

Comment: It's complicated. You need to understand MP4 structure and also how Fragmented MP4 is different (it has new things added). Basically you read the file in PHP and as you receive each packet, you temporarily store it in Array and analyze the byte values.

Comment: You are looking for header section called **MOOV** atom/box (can be at front or back of MP4 bytes) and this lists the byte locations/sizes of each video/audio frame in the video, you must process it (get pieces of info from different atoms, like STSS box tells you which ones are the keyframes, STSZ box tells you the byte size/length of the frames, etc). Basically read the header to reconstruct each frame or group (keyframe + all frames up to next key) as **fragmented** format (a new box called MOOF is required). Try something and ask a question about that when stuck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer. I will must try this and will let you know. Thanks

Comment: Any progress? Or did you solve it some other way?